# SQL Alchemy: "Connection is busy with results from another command" on only the second query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm a developer just not a Python expert, but I inherited some code that I have to get  working.

`StagingConnection` is a SQL Alchemy `Connection` that uses `create_engine`

```
with StagingConnection() as conn, LoadMessageBuffer() as buffer:
   for order in conn.get_current_orders():
         conn.set_order_status(order.id, 'P')
```

`conn.get_current_orders` runs fine, and returns just one row (for testing), and I can see that `set_order_status` has the ID from that row, but then `set_order_status` fails. Both functions are using the `execute()` method on the connection.

Here's the error I get:

> (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: EXEC ? @order_id = ?, @status = ?] [parameters: ('SetOrderStatus', 'LLNW20130722111550', 'P')] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)

Also, the connection has a pool size of 5 by default (and there's only 2 queries here), but I tried bumping it to 20 to see if it just needed more, but that didn't help. Again, I'm very new to this (although a developer for many years), so it's probably something obvious to many people, but I'm not sure why the connection is busy, as to my mind, the only other query it had to run already returned results, and from reading the SQL Alchemy docs, supposedly a new connection from the pool is requested whenever you use `execute()`. So what am I doing wrong, or what should I check?

Comment: Perhaps try `for order in conn.get_current_orders().fetchall():`